# Drag and drop Containerview not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am trying to add a container to my viewcontroller. The container appears when I drag it on to my viewcontroller and give it a different coloured background. However, when I assign a class to it (I made one called SubViewController) it disappears in the simulation.

Theres no code used as its all been done on main.storyboard. But heres an image of the storyboard and simulation next to each other to depict whats happening.

Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

[image: Image here]

Comment: Do you see this view inside the view debugger?

Comment: havent heard of the view debugger - how do I access it?